# Why isn't tabs.onUpdated.addListener() working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey I'm trying to make my chrome extension do something every time a tab's URL gets changed; I've tried seeing I'm using `tabs.onUpdated()` correctly, but nothing happens when I change the URL of my active tab.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
     alert("what?");
});
```

Comment: There are many ways to make a mistake with chrome extensions. Show us your manifest.json and where that code is from (the name of the file).

Comment: {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Drill Sergeant",
  "description": "Tracks time spent on 'watchlist' websites",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "notifications"]
}

Comment: That's really hard on the eyes but as you can see the permissions part includes "tabs"

Comment: I only have a single js script named popup.js; it works with other code until it reaches the onUpdate() part.

Comment: The popup's code runs only when shown. You need to use a background script, see the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).